# devexpress popup control from usercontrol rendered behind of news panel because of z-index

Tags: asp.net, css, devexpress, popupwindow

in my asp.net 4.0 web application i have a jquery based news panel. In that page, a devexpress popup control from a usercontrol appears behind the news panel. I looked at the css of the news panel z-index values ares set to 100.I changed this value to 0, minus values but popup window is still behind of the panel. I try to set the z-index of the popup control to int max but it did not help too.

Any help or clue would be helpful by the way i am using devexpress v10.2.4.

Thank you.

edit: I have updated devex version to v11.2.7  by the way it works perfectly with ie 9 but with ff and chrome i have not been able to see desired result. It seems like a bug or i am missing something i hate when component libraries became unstable between browsers. Still trying to solve the problem i will write here if i'll had one.

Comment: Can you post the HTML somewhere?

Comment: your comment helped me a lot i tried to copy html but i realised that my popup window comes from a user control. There is no problem with a normal popup comes from page but i have problem with popup coming from usercontrol. i am updating question according to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer of the question. It is not a clear answer but hope gives someone a clue about what to do. Check the css settings of the wrapper elements for your popup control. Or take your popup control out of the element and try with this situation in order the understand where the problem.

in my case i just deleted this lines from the css of the div which contains my usercontrol.

```
 border-radius: 6px;
  opacity: 0.9;
```

To summarize check your css carefully.